# php preg_replace usage -

Tags: php, preg-replace

This is the very first time I am trying to use regular expressions, so please have patience.

I would like to use  php preg_replace function to transform a string such as this:

```
"r1=r2+robby+ara"
```

into

```
"ar1b=ar2b+robby+ara"
```

- so  for every occurrence of "r" followed by an integer, I want to place an "a" before it and "b" after it.

I have figured out  the search part, but not the replace part - the question-mark below indicates where I am having troubles. Is there a way to "remember" the integer found by [0-9] and use it in replace string?

```
$s="r1=r2+robby + ara";

$s1=preg_replace ( "/r[0-9]/","ar?b",$s);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but need parentheses:

```
$s="r1=r2+robby + ara";
$s1=preg_replace ( "/r([0-9])/","ar$1b", $s); // produces ar1b=ar2b+robby + ara
```

The `(` and `)` tell PHP to capture whatever is in between (the digit). The `$1` in the replacement tells PHP to use that value (the digit) in that location.

Note: if your problem really is this simple, you don't need parentheses and can use `$0`, which means "the entire matching portion," like in xdazz's answer:

```
$s1=preg_replace ( "/r[0-9]/","a$0b", $s); // produces ar1b=ar2b+robby + ara
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// \0 means the matched part
$s1 = preg_replace('/r\d/', 'a\0b', $s);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
$str_out = preg_replace('/\b(r\d)\b/', 'a$1b', $str_in);
```

`\b` is a word boundary, it prevents, in this case, the replacement of `xr1y`